# House addition. Long flat sewer line under slab, need pump?

Tags: plumbing

Question about an addition im planning. I’m going to try to explain as best as I can and I’ll post a rough picture.

We have a 2 story house over a crawlspace. The plumbing goes into the crawlspace, just under the floor joists, then goes down and into the septic tank.

I’m planning an addition off the garage. It’s going to be a shop with a bedroom and bathroom on the farthest part of it. It’s a 20x30ft addition.

This will be on a slab level with the garage slab, which is about 1 ft lower than the floor joists on the main level. I would say the run of pipe from the new bathroom would be about 35 ft to connect into the main sewer on my house.

My question is, how do I achieve the necessary slope for this? I’m thinking I will need an effluent pump to get it to where it needs to go, but I was hoping to get some additional opinions. It would need to drop about 6 ft by my calculations, putting it way below the level of the main sewer.

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: A quick search shows normal slope to be 0.25" per foot. For 35', that would be ~ 9". Plus 1' because garage lower than house, total < 2 feet.

Comment: I think normal would be to join it in the yard.